# Upload PDF file to server encoding into base64 string with volley in Android

Tags: android, pdf, encoding, compression, android-volley

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I need to upload PDF file to server. I am using Volley to interact with server. But I am having a problem with uploading pdf file to server. I know how to upload image compressing into string. But for PDF, it has problem.

I converted chosen pdf file into base64 encoded string in activity result

```
            if(requestCode==SELECT_BOOK)
            {
                Uri bookUri = data.getData();
                if(bookUri!=null)
                {
                    String filePath = bookUri.toString();
                    String mime = app.getMimeType(filePath);
                    if(mime!=null && !mime.isEmpty() && (mime.toLowerCase()=="application/pdf" || mime.toLowerCase()=="application/txt" || mime.toLowerCase()=="application/text"))
                    {
                        try{
                            InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(bookUri);
                            byte[] byteArray = app.getBytes(iStream);
                            bookFileCompressedString = app.encodeByteArrayIntoBase64String(byteArray);
                            ivBookFile.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_selected);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"An error occurred with file chosen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if(mime.toLowerCase()=="application/pdf")
                        {
                            bookFileExtension = "pdf";
                        }
                        else{
                            bookFileExtension = "txt";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to process file you have chosen.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

These are the methods in app instance (Base64 encode method as well)

```
 public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

    public static String encodeByteArrayIntoBase64String(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Then I post to the server using volley like this

```
param.put("image_file",imageCompressedString);
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, param, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    closeFixedMortalLoading();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Book successfully contributed. Thank you.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    closeFixedMortalLoading();
                    String errorMessages = AppSingleton.ParseVolleyErrorMessageToString(error);
                    if(errorMessages!=null && !errorMessages.isEmpty())
                    {
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonError = new JSONObject(errorMessages);
                            showServerErrors(jsonError);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error in parsing data from server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put(AppSingleton.API_KEY_FIELD,AppSingleton.API_KEY);
                    headers.put(AppSingleton.AUTH_TOKEN_FIELD,app.getAuthToken());
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

As you can see I passed encoded string. But the Volley request just keep sending to the server and  never ends. Does not reach to error listener as well. That is maybe because data of compressed file my be too large. So I log the compressed string to know.

This is what I got

[image]

As you can see, there are many lines displayed in logcat even though I log only once like below.

```
Log.i("COMPRESSED_STRING",bookFileCompressedString);
```

So I assumed that volley could not able to send to server because data was too large. Mean result of encoding pdf file is too large. That is why even log showing multiple lines. How can I compress and upload pdf file to server using Volley?

Comment: It is normal that the log shows many lines. It is called wrapping.

Comment: First of all base 64 does not **compress** it **increases** the file size by **1.3 times**. Second thing the issue that might be is the string of this size will take some time to generate(depending on the file size), you should use a listener to check if the string is computed before sending the request.

Comment: I wonder why you use base64 to upload that file. It increases the amount of bytes that have to be transferred. Volley kan of course upload a file as is.

Comment: `you should use a listener to check if the string is computed before sending the request`. ??? The string will be there when the encoding function returns. And how would one attach a listener?

Comment: `closeFixedMortalLoading();`. ????

Comment: You can just send only hundred bytes of your base64 string and see if the server receives them.

Comment: If I dont base64, the file will be byte arrray. So how alcan I send it to server converting to compressed string please? Pls how to implement callback as well? Can I get simple code?

Comment: Pls how to create listener that is fired when compressing or encoding process is finished?